# Conditional serialization with Microsoft.AspNet.Odata

Tags: .net, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, odata

We have a requirement to hide certain fields based on user permissions when transmitting data to the client application.

This *should* be simple using Json.Net and its ShouldSerialize methods....unfortunately Microsoft's implementation of OData does not seem to use Json.net as its internal serializer.  I'm not locked to using the Json.net solution; it just seems to be the most likely candidate for success.

I have been attempting to implement a customer serializer for OData, but the only examples I have been able to find seem to be from several years ago and are no longer correct.
We are using the newest version of the Microsoft.AspNet.Odata package and are unable to revert as we are leveraging much of the new functionality.

I've been playing with this for a few days, and it seems that something like what I have below should be the answer, but I've had no luck so far.

```
    public class NewtonsoftODataMediaTypeFormatter:ODataMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public NewtonsoftODataMediaTypeFormatter(IEnumerable<ODataPayloadKind> payloadKinds)
            : base(payloadKinds)
        {

        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(
            Type type,
            object value,
            Stream writeStream,
            HttpContent content,
            TransportContext transportContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
            {
                writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```